# Configure Email Token with Flask Factory Application create_app

Tags: python, flask, token, config, factory

I am getting confused with configurations and imports once I started using the Flask factory application pattern.

I am creating an application with the function create_app in #app/**init**.py
I have a config file for setting the development/testing/production variables, and an instance folder with another config file.

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app=Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    etc...
    return app
```

I am using blueprints and have an authentication view in #app/auth/views.py
I am trying to set up email confirmation tokens using URLSafeTimedSerializer...

```
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer

@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    ts = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    token = ts.dumps(self.email, salt='email-confirm-key')
    etc...
```

Now my problem is, my variable 'ts' needs the app.config['SECRET_KEY'] set. But I am unable to define the app variable (as is shown in all online tutorials). I get an error when I try to import...(in #app/auth/views.py)

```
from .. import app
```

and when I try to import like...

```
from .. import create_app
```

Can someone shine light on how to initialize modules using 'app' and app.config outside the flask app factory create_app?

Hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario you should use `Flask.current_app`

```
from flask import current_app

...

ts = URLSafeTimedSerializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
```

From [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.current_app):

> **flask.current_app**
>
> Points to the application handling the request. This
>   is useful for extensions that want to support multiple applications
>   running side by side. This is powered by the application context and
>   not by the request context, so you can change the value of this proxy
>   by using the app_context() method.

[This link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/) aso explains further details about the Flask application factory methodology, in particular using `current_app` to access the app configuration.